# What is $x$ given that $x^{log_4(x)- 2} = 2^{3log_4(x)-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

My math teacher had given me four problems on a sheet of paper, and I am unable to solve this last one:

Given that $x^{\log_4(x - 2)} = 2^{3\log_4(x-1)}$, solve for $x$.

I've tried numerous things such as simplifying the right hand side to $(x-1)^\frac{3}{2}$ and changing the left hand side to $(x-2)^{\log_4x}$ to no avail.

From the way the question has been written, the equality could also be **read** as:
$x^{(\log_4x)-2} = 2^{3(\log_4x)-1}$

Edit:
It seems that the equation is supposed to be
$x^{(\log_4x)-2} = 2^{3((\log_4x)-1)}$

From WolframAlpha, I know the solutions are $x=2$ and $x=64$, but I don't know how to derive it.

Comment: The way you rewrote the equality is incorrect: Logarithms don't satisfy $\log(x+y)=\log(x)+\log(y)$

Comment: I would make sure you read the problem correctly because Wolfram cannot find an exact solution. Of course it may be possible to find it, but unlikely if this problem is from a precal class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^{(\log_4x)-2} = 2^{3(\log_4x-1)}\\\implies (\log_4(x)-2)\log_4(x) = (3\log_4(x)-3)\log_4(2)\stackrel{u=\log_4(x)}{\implies}(u-2)u = \frac 12(3u - 3)$$
Now you have a quadratic in $u$. Can you solve it from there?

Comment: My mistake, but I accidentally put $2^{3\log_4{x}-1}$ instead of $2^{3(\log_4{x}-1)}$.
I'll give you the check mark when you modify your answer to fit the edited version.

Comment: @JamesWu fixed ${}$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $2 = 4^{1/2}$. Express your solution in base 4 as $x = 4^t$ and try to solve this again. It is also worth mentioning that $\log$ doesn't "distribute" as you have done. That is, $\log(x-1) \neq \log(x) - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $$x^{\log_4(x - 2)} = 2^{3\log_4(x-1)}=8^{\log_4(x-1)}\Rightarrow x\gt 8$$

On the other hand $$x^{\log_4(x - 2)} = 2^{3\log_4(x-1)}=4^{\frac32\log_4(x-1)}=4^{\log_4(x-1)^{\frac 32}}$$ It follows the trascendental equation $$x^{\log_4(x - 2)}=(x-1)^{\frac 32}$$

An approximation gives (*we have seen above that $x\gt 8$*) $$\color{red}{x\approx 9.1799}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\log_4 x.$ Then $4^A=x.$ So $$2^{-1+3\log_4 x}=4^{-1/2+(3/2)\log_4x}=4^{-1/2+3A/2}$$ and $$x^{-2+\log_4x}=(4^A)^{(-2+\log_4x)}=(4^A)^{(-2+A)}=4^{-2A+A^2}.$$ So $x$ is a solution iff $-1/2+3A/2=-2A+A^2.$